# Do we need the join clause for outer joins in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

[This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) gives the following example of outer join:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}

public static void LeftOuterJoinExample()
{
    Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
    Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
    Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
    Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

    Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
    Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
    Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
    Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
    Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

    // Create two lists.
    List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
    List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

    var query = from person in people
                join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };

    foreach (var v in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1}", v.FirstName + ":", v.PetName);
    }
}

// This code produces the following output: 
// 
// Magnus:         Daisy 
// Terry:          Barley 
// Terry:          Boots 
// Terry:          Blue Moon 
// Charlotte:      Whiskers 
// Arlene:
```

What is the point of the `join` keyword?  The following query has the same result.

```
var query2 = from person in people
             from pet in pets.Where (p => p.Owner.Equals(person)).DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (pet == null ? String.Empty : pet.Name) };
```

Are these two functionally equivalent? If not, how are they different? If yes, what are the advantages of using the `join` key word for outer joins? Seems like a fancy way of writing the 'where' clause. But maybe there are other contexts where it is really useful?

Note: I realize that most likely the join clause is also used for inner joins, group joins and such, I'd like to understand if there is ever a reason to  use it for outer joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linq-to-Objects they will compile to different queries and may have significantly different performance.

The `join` operator will internally create a `Lookup` for the "right-hand" set that will make retrieving the matching results much faster since it organizes items by hash code.

Using a `Where` clause will perform the lookups in the following manner (rough pseudo-code, not the exact implementation):

```
foreach(var left in leftSet)
{
   foreach(var right in rightSet)
   {
      if(left.key equals right.key)
          yields return result
   }
}
```

for every object in the left collection, you're doing a full scan of the right collection to find "matching" objects.  For large sets, the performance impact can be very significant.

Note that the `Where` method makes is possible to do "joins" that are not possible with `join` since `join` only supports equi-joins.

With Ling-to-SQL, Linq-to-EF, etc. the difference depends greatly on the underlying query provider.  You may very well get similar performance with a cross-join/where than with a left join, but you'd have to try it and measure to be certain.

Comment: Oh, this is good. Thank you. I'll wait a day or so in case someone else wants to chime in, but that's more or less what I was after.

Comment: @Cool.J.Banana I think the above answer is correct as JOIN expressions are optimized for these kind of operations.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use it for inner joins, either, but in many cases doing this logic in the "where" clause is less efficient. This becomes more apparent when it is done for a table that has a foreign key index rather than a simple collection of objects.

I know your question is about LINQ, but since many of these concepts come from SQL this is worth mentioning: Historically, some dialects of SQL didn't have join clauses at all - you would list the tables with commas, and do all your logic in the where clause, with various vendor-specific syntax [`(+)` on the tables for Oracle, `*=` and `=*` for left/right joins on MS SQL, etc] to indicate an outer join.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm guessing SQL starts becoming relevant only when we get to the LINQ provider level, but the question is not specific to a particular provider. This query becomes an expression tree before any (potential) SQL is ever spit by the provider. I do agree that the query syntax was most likely informed by existing SQL dialects, but I'm not so sure about semantics - semantics feels pretty different from any SQL dialects I came across.